# Error in bundled controller when not autowiring

Tags: symfony

Symfony documentation states that [public bundles should explicitly configure their services and not rely on autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#public-and-reusable-bundles). As such, I am using the below to configure a Controller service in my bundle.

```
<service id="blah\blah\SecurityController">
    <argument type="service" id="security.authentication_utils"/>
    <tag name="controller.service_arguments"/>
    <tag name="container.service_subscriber"/>
</service>
```

*The security argument is because I am using authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError() within a login method.*

However, such a service definition produces a deprecation error. `User Deprecated: Auto-injection of the container for "blah\blah\SecurityController" is deprecated since Symfony 4.2. Configure it as a service instead. at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Controller/ControllerResolver.php:64)`

If I simply add `autowire="true"` to the service definition above, the error goes away (at which point I don't need that existing argument either). However, I would like to follow Symfony recommendations about explicit configuration.

What am I missing that is being auto-injected when autowire is set to true that I need to explicitly include?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the deprecation, I assume your controller is extending AbstractController.

There are two possible approaches to solve this deprecation:

1. If you are using functionality from AbstractController not at all or only barely, you can just not extend anything at all. If you use e.g. only one function from AbstractController, you might choose to re-implement it to reduce your dependencies. This is also mentioned in the [official docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html#alternatives-to-base-controller-methods).
2. If you want to keep extending AbstractController, you need to inject the container manually. E.g. like this:

services.xml

```
<service id="App\Controller\FooController">
    <call method="setContainer">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
    </call>
</service>
```

FooController.php

```
class FooController extends AbstractController {}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Yes, this controller extends AbstractController. I followed the example closer to your original, unedited answer that follows the "typical" dependency injection technique. Simply adding "ContainerInterface $container" to the __construct and setting the argument with id service_container in my services.xml. No more error.

Comment: is extending Controller (not AbstractController)

Comment: @justinvoelker You should not be injecting the container into the constructor.  You should be extending from AbstractController.  Please consider updating your question with the top part of your controller.  Though this questions seem oddly similar to the one from yesterday.

Comment: @Cerad As I understood justinvoelker, they are (still) extending AbstractController, so I don't see the problem. Also, can you maybe link the other question you mentioned?

Comment: Similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56370800) but yesterday's error was preventing the controller from working at all, this one was just a deprecation warning I was trying to solve. If you feel they are too similar, please remove this one. I am extending AbstractController and that is where the error is coming from, is my understanding. That the container is not being auto-injected (it's right there in the error). So, manual-injecting seems like a reasonable solution. And if not injecting into the constructor, at least the most recent answer with the setContainer method.

Comment: @justinvoelker The first problem is that you accepted an answer but indicated in the comments that you have done something completely different making the question/answer combo pretty much useless to anyone who has a similar problem.  Yes injecting the container in the constructor "works" but the abstract controller uses a service locator which is basically a subset of the container.  Kind of hard to explain without getting into the bowels of di.  If we knew what you were doing then maybe we could help.  Up to you.

Comment: @Cerad, I accepted the answer because it, at one point, was a different answer that also worked. Both the original and edited answers work so it is still my accepted answer. As the title states, this error is in a bundled controller. Controllers in a bundle are not auto-wired since they don't live in the expected "src" directory of an app. Symfony docs say to avoid autowiring inside bundles so that's what I was trying to do. When a controller extending AbstractController is not autowired, you get this error where the container is not auto injected. I guess I'm not seeing the problem. Sorry.